How to add the generated key firebase admin sdk in your andriod project when you have the google-service.json and generated private key
I am new to firebase i integrate firebase with andriod studio but my company firebase doesn't give me the write access when i asked they provide me with generated private key for firebase admin sdk so that i can write in the firebase storage but i don't know how to use that generated private key? when i am already using goole-service.json as a configuration of firebase.
I tried using firebase-admin dependency but .setCredentails still not coming
I want to add that private generated firebase admin sdk json file to integrate with my code so that i can write it in firebase storage.

It's not a good idea to use firebase-admin and a service account in an Android app.  That's a huge security hole if the app is ever published.

@DougStevenson what will be the other way i don't have the write access to the firebase what should i ask to directly give write access to my firebase account or should i use .setApiKey() to have the write access

As Doug said, it's an anti-pattern to try and use the admin SDK in a client-side app. It also sounds like a XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish with the Admin SDK?

I just want write access to the firebase account for my andriod app to upload files to the cloud storage on company’s firebase.Do you know any way? @FrankvanPuffelen

That doesn't require an Admin SDK. How to upload files through the Firebase SDK for Android is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start
